# stack-overflow-like content ranking for wordpress?

Tags: plugins

**drastically EDITed:**

What approach would you recommend for **post** ranking in wordpress CMS? should it work with custom fields? something else?

i couldn't find a plugin to do it, so i'm going to to write one by myself.

i know how to use a database, and i'm a php programmer. but i'd prefer to rely as much as possible on WP existing components or features.

Comment: You're asking a lot in one question: 1) how to write a wordpress plugin, 2) how to rank posts, 3) how to write a database. I think you should probably ask these sorts of questions individually to keep the scope of your question narrow.

Comment: There are at least 3 different questions here.. I think you should reformulate it as one specific question. I've never written a wordpress plugin before, but I'd start by writing a [hello world plugin](http://www.google.com/search?q=wordpress+plugin+%22hello+world%22)

Comment: thanks for the comments. i think my question is now very specific.

Answer (score 1):

The WPMU DEV team has created the [Q&A plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/qa/), and it's described as:

> Q&A allows any WordPress site to have
>   a fully featured questions and answers
>   section - just like StackOverflow,
>   Yahoo Answers, Quora and more...except
>   better

Answer (score 0):

For what its worth, I find the ranking algorithm on the [IMDB Top 250](http://www.imdb.com/chart/top) page pretty good. It gives a weighted rating to movies so that so-so popular and older movies aren't unfairly advantaged against amazing new or obscure movies.

Here's the algorithm:

```
 weighted rating (WR) = (v ÷ (v+m)) × R + (m ÷ (v+m)) × C 

where:

    R = average for the movie from 1 - 10 (mean) = (Rating)
    v = number of votes for the movie = (votes)
    m = minimum votes required to be listed in the Top 250 (currently 3000)
    C = the mean vote across the whole report (currently 6.9)
```

Comment: thanks, but the math is less a concern. see my edited question.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of rating type plugins for WordPress.

Search WPSE (this site) for ratings, stackexchange, votes and you'll see plenty of previously answered questions on this topic.